Group with generators $x,y$ such that $x^2=y^2$

What is the group $G$ generated by elements $x,y$ such that $|x|=6$, $y^2=x^2$ and $yx=x^{-1}y$?

I found $G=\{e,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,y,xy,x^2y,x^3y,x^4y,x^5y\}$ which has 12 elements and not  abelien. However, there are only 3 nonabelian groups of order 12 which is the dihedral group $D_6$, the alternating group $A_4$, and the semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$. But none of these three satisfies the generators of $G$. Is the group $G$ really has 12 elements or more than that? Any hint what group is this?

There is no such group. From $yx=x^{-1}y$ we get $yx^2 = x^{-2}y$, but $y^2=x^2$ implies that $y$ commutes with $x^2$, so $x^2 = x^{-2}$ and $x$ cannot have order $6$.
The group defined by the presentation $$\langle x,y \mid x^6=1, x^2=y^2, yx=x^{-1}y \rangle $$
has order $4$ and its generator $x$ has order $2$ not $6$. The relation $x^6=1$ says that $x$ has order dividing $6$; it need not be exactly $6$.
